# WGCNA soft threshold selection

Tags: wgcna

Here I am conducting WGCNA analysis. When calculating the soft threshold, it is basically bel[image]ow 0.8. I choose Power=6, which only has 0 and 7. Is it feasible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please copy-paste text as text into question posts. This makes the text easier to read on some devices, and allows it to be more easily modified when required.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the context (how many samples, what tissue, experimental design etc) but the mean and median connectivities are pretty high at power 6. I would first check the data for strong drivers of correlation and possibly adjust for them if they do not seem biologically relevant to the question you study. Assuming you find no issues, I would go with a higher power here, maybe 12.